# jQuery loop / .each function to simplify code

Tags: jquery, loops, each

I’d like to simplify the following code. I think using the `.each` function or a loop will do it but I need your help.

```
var totalImages1 = $( '#project-1 li' ).length;
$( '#project-1 li' ).each( function( k, v ) {
  $( '.number', v ).html( String( k+1 ) + ' / ' + totalImages1 );
});

var totalImages2 = $( '#project-2 li' ).length;
$( '#project-2 li' ).each( function( k, v ) {
  $( '.number', v ).html( String( k+1 ) + ' / ' + totalImages2 );
});

var totalImages3 = $( '#project-2 li' ).length;
$( '#project-3 li' ).each( function( k, v ) {
  $( '.number', v ).html( String( k+1 ) + ' / ' + totalImages3 );
});
```

Here’s the corresponding html:

```
<div class="slider-container" id="project-1">
  <ul class="slider">
    <li>
      <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="">
      <p class="caption"><span class="number"></span> This is a caption</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div class="slider-container" id="project-2">
  <ul class="slider">
    <li>
      <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="">
      <p class="caption"><span class="number"></span> This is a caption</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="">
      <p class="caption"><span class="number"></span> This is another caption</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="">
      <p class="caption"><span class="number"></span> The third caption</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="">
      <p class="caption"><span class="number"></span> The third caption</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div class="slider-container" id="project-3">
  <ul class="slider">
    <li>
      <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="">
      <p class="caption"><span class="number"></span> This is a caption</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="">
      <p class="caption"><span class="number"></span> This is another caption</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="">
      <p class="caption"><span class="number"></span> The third caption</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can loop through the parent elements using multiple selector like

```
$('#project-1, #project-2, #project-3').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        $lis = $this.find('li'),
        totalImages = $lis.length;
    $lis.each(function (k, v) {
        $('.number', v).html((k + 1) + ' / ' + totalImages);
    });

})
```

But if you can assign a common class to all those 3 parent elements then you can

```
$('.project').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        $lis = $this.find('li'),
        totalImages = $lis.length;
    $lis.each(function (k, v) {
        $('.number', v).html((k + 1) + ' / ' + totalImages);
    });

})
```

Answer (score 0):

`Arun P Johny` has answered it correctly.

Alternatively, you can also use the [**starts with**](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector of jQuery

```
$('div[id^="project-"] li').each( function(){
    //your code.
});
```

Also, in your particular case, you need not worry about finding `div`s that have `id`s of the pattern `project-*`

Your `ul`elements can be targeted directly, like,

```
$('ul.slider li').each(function(){
    //your code.
});
```